# What is the value of the angle x in the figure below?

Tags: geometry

For reference:
[image]

My progress: I couldn't find any notable triangles, no cyclic quadrilaterals…maybe I need an additional trace

$\measuredangle E = 129^o -\theta\\
\measuredangle DGB = 133^o -\theta\\
x = \theta+47^o$

[image]

Comment: Some information seems to be missing. $x$ is not unique.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The figure does not uniquely determine $x$.  You can immediately see this by noting that the upper triangle $\triangle ABD$ with angles $17^\circ$, $47^\circ$, is fixed.  So is $\angle DAF$.  But $F$ itself is not fixed by any of the other constraints.  In other words, you are free to draw any ray from $B$, which intersects the lower line at $F$, and $AD$ at $G$, then draw $E$ on $BD$ such that $\angle BFE = 51^\circ$.

I have included an animation to illustrate that $x$ is not fixed.  The location of this angle is at the red dot.  It is not difficult to verify that all criteria in the diagram are satisfied.

[image]

---

I honestly do not understand why you cannot accept that your question does not have a unique solution.  You should not need to see the angle measures to be convinced, but since you continue to fail to understand, I have provided two static images illustrating different solutions as follows:

[image]
[image]

In each case, the points $A, B, C, D$ are fixed because these are uniquely determined by the given information in your original diagram.  However, points $E$, $F$, and $G$ are not fixed.  The only condition on these points is that $F$ must lie on line $AC$, $E$ must lie on $BC$, and $\angle BFE = 51^\circ$.  But this is **OBVIOUSLY** possible in infinitely many ways. You still have not provided any mathematical justification for why you somehow think that the angles $\angle FBE$ and $\angle BEF$, whose measures are not specified in the original diagram, must be uniquely determined, whereas I have now provided multiple examples where they are not.

Comment: But $\triangle BEF$ is fixed. So $F$ is also fixed because the angles $\theta and \measuredangle E$ that are fixed isn't it??

Comment: @petaarantes No.  Please see the animation I have added to my answer.

Comment: Its cool animation..but $\angle BEF$ seems to be varying as does $\angle FBE$ and they are fixed...?

Comment: If it's not bothersome, you could post an image with the written angle measurements...

Comment: @petaarantes In your own original diagram, $\angle BEF$ and $\angle FBE$ are not labeled with any angle measures.  What makes you think they are fixed?

Comment: @petaarantes Let's ask the same question another way.  If either of those two angles you mentioned were specified, it would become **trivial** to calculate $\angle x$; e.g., $\angle x = \angle FBE + 47^\circ$.  Since they are not specified, and I have shown you an animation in which all the known angles furnished in the diagram remain fixed, it is **not possible** to conclude that $\angle FBE$ must be constant.

Comment: $\theta$ is fixed because $\measuredangle ABE$ is fixed ($116^o$) ..$\measuredangle BFE$ ´s fixed $51^o$..F depends on $\theta$ and the slope of $13^o$ in $A$  which are fixed values ...Maybe I'm confused... If I saw an image with the angles placed I could see it better

Comment: Yes FBE is $\theta$ + 47 ... but in these Peruvian exercises they use auxiliary constructions ... iit looks like they are missing data but in the end they draw lines forming auxiliary figures that lead to the solution ... but maybe some data is really missing ...

Comment: @petaarantes I have now added more images in accordance with your request.  I have nothing more to tell you; if you still refuse to understand, I can no longer provide any help.

Comment: no problems..thank you for your efforts in trying to explain to me..

Comment: It's not about refusing to understand...I just couldn't visualize it the way you interpreted it...I can't accept your explanation just to agree with you...people don't have the same level of knowledge...the quality of those who teach is to see and demonstrate what others did not understand...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129703/discussion-between-peta-arantes-and-heropup).